# Wrong SQL result after transient failures when using EnableRetryOnFailure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have program that controls industrial production equipment and is always performing tasks in a loop. Part of these tasks is checking values in an SQLServer database.

Now and then (a few times per day) we would get transient failures which caused the program to have to be manually restarted. To prevent this I have enabled the EnableRetryOnFailure option for UseSqlServer. The program now doesn't crash anymore but sometimes takes wrong decisions.

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, o =>
    {
        o.EnableRetryOnFailure();
    });
});
```

Example of query results **without** `EnableRetryOnFailure`:

Ever second we do `SELECT count(*) FROM table` (via linq):

```
1500
1500
1500
1500
Exception: Transient Failure....
1500
1500
```

Example of query results **with** `EnableRetryOnFailure`:

Ever second we do `SELECT count(*) FROM table` (via linq):

```
1500
1500
1500
1500
0
1500
1500
```

Is this a known bug in EF Core? If anything getting wrong results is WORSE than getting an exception..
Would switching to using shared memory lead to less transient failures?
Using EF Core 2.2, .net Core 2.2 SQL Server 2014

Comment: Post the query. Retrying won't change the result. As for using shared memory and transient failures - why would you get *any* kind of failure connecting to a local database? I'd be *really* worried if connecting to a local database failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the errors were because of concurrency issues. (Insert at the same time as read.) And it was a bug in efcore that the retry would give a wrong answer. It was fixed in efcore 3 and up.